# Show that a set S in R^n is convex if and only if every convex combination of a finite number of points in S is in S.

Tags: linear-programming

I am stuck on the first direction of the if and only if statement:

Let K be an arbitrary number of points in S

S is a convex set $\rightarrow$ $x' = \sum_{i=1}^k c_ix_i\in S$ and $\sum_{i=1}^k c_i = 1$

If I'm understanding this question correctly, how do I go on to prove this?

Update: Induction attempt

Base case: Let k = 2

Show $x' = c_1x_1 + c_2x_2\in S$ and $c_1 + c_2 = 1$

Trivially true by definition of a convex set, if $x_1,x_2 \in S$ so is their line segment.

Hypothesis: Assume $\forall x_i \in S$ such that $x' = \sum_{i = 1}^kc_ix_i \in S$ and $\sum_{i = 1}^kc_i = 1$ holds

Induction step: Show $x' = \sum_{i = 1}^{k + 1}c_ix_i \in S$ and $\sum_{i = 1}^{k+1}c_i = 1$

$x' = \sum_{i = 1}^kc_ix_i + c_{k+1}x_{k+1}$

So for this last line, theres something that makes x' exist in S, but I don't quite know what.

Comment: Try induction, Try anything.

Comment: For any element in S, its line segment is also in S @cineel

Comment: @copper.hat For the base case, if we assume k = 2 for example x' = c1 * x1 + c2 * x2 I assume this is in the convex set but why

Comment: Ah nevermind, its because x' is a point on the lines segment of two points in S, by definition also in S. Lemme try finishing this proof

Comment: yeah i'm still stuck on the induction step haha, i'll add it once i make more progress

Comment: No, because my question is asking about a finite amount of points in S, every convex combination can be infinite.

Comment: My question is just a weaker version I guess

Comment: convex combination is a finite sum by definition